# Search in a table using full or partial

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a little problem where i try to search for a product and the user can choose to click on a full search or a partial search. Problem is when the user click on full search and type in something, the whole table is printing out and the word of the product is not (i want instead printing out the product and not the whole table) And with partial search, its just print outs it dont find a match. Below here is my code so far:

```
// DB configuration //
if (!isset($_POST["searchtype"])) {
echo "<form method='POST'>";
echo "Search for product:<br>";
# using html5 input type search 
echo "<input type='text' name='searchtext' size='15' placeholder='search' results='5' autosave='saved-searches'>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Full search";
echo"<input type='radio' value='FULL' checked name='searchtype'><br>";
echo "Partial search ";
echo "<input type='radio' name='searchtype' value='PARTIAL'>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Search' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";


  }
  else {
$searchtext = $_POST["searchtext"]; # Retrieve from the form
$searchtype = $_POST["searchtype"]; # Retrieve from the form
$searchtext_san = sanitize_form_text($searchtext); # Prevents SQL injections!


            try{
    if($DBH == null)
        $DBH = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);


      $sql = "select name, price, details from products where name='$searchtext_san'";


    if ($searchtype == "FULL"){

        $sql .= " = :searchtext_san";       
        $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);     
        $STH->execute(array(':searchtext_san' => $searchtext_san));

    }

    if ($searchtype == "PARTIAL"){

        $sql .= " LIKE ':searchtext_san'";
        $STH = $DBH->prepare($sql);
        $STH->execute(array(':searchtext_san' => '%'.$searchtext_san.'%'));
    }


    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $total = $STH->rowCount();
    if ($total == 0){
        echo "Sorry, no matches found!";
    }
    if ($total > 0){
        while ($row = $STH->fetch()){

            echo "{$row["name"]} {$row["price"]} {$row["details"]}<br>";
        }
    } 

    $DBH = null;
     }
    catch (PDOException $e){
    echo '<b>PDOException: </b>',$e->getMessage();
    die();
    }
    }

    function sanitize_form_text($t)
    {
    $t = strip_tags($t);
     $t = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9@._-]", "", $t);
      return $t;
     }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for fulltext search

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

[Full text Search description](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

for partial search you can us `like`

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE name  RLIKE '[yourtext]'
```